# Sintax in python 2.7.2

Tags: python-3.x, wapiti

I'm trying to use the app wapiti to make some security test in a web project running in localhost, but i have some problems with the syntax of Python. I follow the instructions that they give in wapiti project site and write this:

```
C:\Python27\python C:\Wapiti\wapiti.py http://server.com/base/url/
```

but i get this:

```
SintaxError: Invalid Sintax
```

I had read that the syntax of python changed in that version... I really need help please.

Comment: Please paste the *actual* error message you got into this question. Don't retype it from what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Wapiti prefers Python 2.3. I'm judging by Wapiti's copyright date of 2006 and a note in its manual that one of its options doesn't work in Python 2.4.

You can simply install Python 2.3. If it's within your skills, you might want to install it in a virtual machine or a Python virtualenv.

Comment: Python is pretty good about backwards compatibility. Do you know of any specific examples where a valid 2.3 script would cause a syntax error in Python 2.7?

Comment: @GregHewgill: `as = 10` should do it, but I don't seem to have any problems running wapiti.py under 2.7.

Comment: Quite right, that even works on 2.4 (the oldest Python I have handy). I had thought `as` was a reserved word from way back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do this setting first

Go to control panel->system security->system->Advance system settings->click Environmentvariables--> change the path in listbox->
variable value =;C:\Python27\ concatenate this with actual text..

1. run command prompt
2. go to wapiti file path

example:

```
D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src\python wapiti.py http://domainname.com/ -[options]
D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src\python wapiti.py http://domainname.com/ -s
D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src\python wapiti.py http://domainname.com/ -h
```